# Swift protocols and type recurrences — is it possible?

Tags: swift

I try to build protocols ProtocolA, ProtocolB and ProtocolC and classes based on them where:

```
public protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype B: ProtocolB
    associatedtype C: ProtocolC
    var arrayB: [B] {get set}
    var someNumber: C {get set}
}

public protocol ProtocolB {
    associatedtype A: ProtocolA
    associatedtype C = A.C
    var arrayC: [C] {get set}
    var parent: A? {get set}
}

public protocol ProtocolC {
    init()
}
```

It looks OK, I can define Classes:

```
open class ClassA<BC:ProtocolB, CC:ProtocolC>: ProtocolA {
    public typealias B = BC
    public typealias C = CC
    public var someNumber: CC = CC()
    public var arrayB: [BC] = []
}

open class ClassB<AC:ProtocolA> : ProtocolB{
    open var arrayC: [AC.C] = []
    public typealias A = AC
    public typealias C = AC.C // 
    public var parent: AC? = nil
}

open class ClassC: ProtocolC {
    required public init()  {
    }
}
```

But now, there is no way to init ClassA or ClassB:

```
let c = ClassC() // OK
let b = ClassB<ClassA<ClassB<ClassA.....>>>, ClassC>() // No way
let a = ClassA<ClassB<ClassA<ClassB...>>>, ClassC>() // No way either
```

Is any way to workaround this and similar problems?

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a good case for generics.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve using this technique?

Comment: Pretty hard to describe: I know I will have exactly same data structure but with different classes. In one case ClassC will be like Float, in case other like Double or Int. ClassB or BetterClassB:ClassB. But maybe I’m wrong. I’m learning and trying maybe stupid ideas.

Comment: @Łukasz Try describing your original problem in more detail. I would rather help you solve your main problem than lead you down a dark path

Comment: Ok, but I will need more time. Next days. ok?

Comment: @matt I don't believe it should be deleted or can't be answered, while it might not be something one should for production code, it's still an interesting exercise useful for better understanding the language.

Comment: This feels like a misuse of PATs. What generic algorithm would make use of this type (i.e. what kind of extension would you write on ProtocolA, or what kind of generic function would include `<A: ProtocolA>` in its signature)? Particularly mixing PATs with generic classes that can be subclassed is almost always a sign that something has gone wrong. PATs and generic classes solve similar problems of polymorphism in orthogonal ways; if you think you need both at the same time, something is very suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some parts (like ProtocolC) irrelevant to this circular declaration problem for brevity and here we are:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype B: ProtocolB
    var arrayB: [B] {get set}
}

protocol ProtocolB {
    associatedtype A: ProtocolA
    var parent: A? {get set}
}

protocol TypeProviderProtocol {
    associatedtype A: ProtocolA
    associatedtype B: ProtocolB
}

struct TypeProvider: TypeProviderProtocol {
    typealias A = ClassA<TypeProvider>
    typealias B = ClassB<TypeProvider>
}

class ClassA<T: TypeProviderProtocol>: ProtocolA {
    typealias B = T.B
    var arrayB: [B] = []

    func actionA() {
        print("in ClassA")
    }
}

class ClassB<T: TypeProviderProtocol> : ProtocolB{
    typealias A = T.A
    var parent: A? = nil

    func actionB() {
        print("in ClassB")
    }
}

let a = ClassA<TypeProvider>()
let b = ClassB<TypeProvider>()

a.arrayB = [b]
b.parent = a

for child in a.arrayB {
    // we know exact type of ClassA children so we can call it here
    child.actionB()
}

// and the same for ClassB parent type
b.parent?.actionA()
```